# ThreeJS - How to add an environment map on top of loaded materials?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi I am new at ThreeJS I am trying to add an Environment Map on top of the materials loaded using JSON loader... This is how I am trying to do it:

```
var gun = null;
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load("obj/nissan/nissan-gt-r-nismo.json", function(geometry, materials){

    var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        envMap: cubeMap,
        shininess: 2.0
    });

    materials.push(mat);

    var matface = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);

    gun = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, matface);
    gun.scale.set(0.5,0.5, 0.5);
    scene.add(gun);

} );
```

However, it seems the environment map is overwritten by the materials loaded by the JSONloader, (Environment mapping works when I remove the loaded materials)

On a side note, is it better to use JSONLoader or ObjectLoader?

UPDATE: I FIXED THIS BY ITERATING THROUGH THE LIST OF MATERIALS AND SETTING ENVMAP.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < materials.length; i++){
        materials[i].envMap = cubeMap;

        if(materials[i].name =="body-paint"){
            materials[i].reflectivity = 0.2;
        }
    }
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should not add a new material for the envMap but set it for your existing (possibly single) material.

And using JSONLoader is I think good when you know that your JSON is that format, that's what most of the examples do too.